# How to use different DisplayTemplates for the Same ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I need two different DisplayTemplates for the same ViewModel. One is for displaying the ViewModel on a regular page, and the other is for displaying the ViewModel on a print-friendly page. My ViewModels all derive from a base model, and DisplayFor figures out which DisplayTemplate to use when i give it a List of the base model.

As i can understand, DisplayFor looks for a filename in the DisplayTemplates folder that equals the type of the model it has been passed. I cannot have multiple files with the same name.

How can i solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an overload of `DisplayFor` which allows you to pass the template name.  If you name the print template by adding `Print` after the model name, you can then call the print template like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyModel, "MyModelPrint")
```